# Adding noise to speech signal

Tags: matlab, file-io, signal-processing, noise

I'm attempting to add noise to a speech signal (`.wav` file) in matlab using the following method:

```
load handel.mat;

hfile= 'noisy.wav';

y = wavread('daveno.wav');
y = y + randn(size(y)) * (1/100);
wavwrite(y, Fs, hfile);
nsamples=Fs;
```

This adds the noise, however, it removes the actual speech spoken word and therefore, the noise is only contained. Do I need to multiply by a bigger number, or, could anyone please suggest a way to fix this problem?

Comment: if you leave off the line where you add the noise, does it work? If it does then maybe you just need noise with a smaller amplitude. Maybe you can try `y = y + randn(size(y)) * (max(abs(y)/100));`

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the reply. When I leave off the line where I add noise, it completely messes up the signal, in that, it sounds like a robot and the timing is completely out. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `Fs`, maybe you're not sampling at a high enough frequency. Maybe try `[y, Fs] = wavread('daveno.wav')` to get a good `Fs`?

Comment: @Dan You could be right. Is there a way to read in the sampling rate at read in, and, keep it, and, then write with the same sampling frequency?

Comment: @Dan Got it :) Please make your comment an answer and I'll accept! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are writing the file at the wrong sampling frequency. Find the correct sampling frequency (i.e. the value for `Fs`) using the second output of [wavread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html)

```
   [y, Fs] = wavread('daveno.wav')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, greatly appreciated. Enjoy the rest of your day/evening/night :)